# VBA validation not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to return an error message if the `cbo_moduleName` field is empty once the **submit** button is clicked but nothing is happening.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

    If IsEmpty(cbo_moduleName.Value) Then
        MsgBox ("Module Name field empty!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Any idea where I am making my mistake?

Comment: How is cbo_moduleName.Value defined?  Might it have a value, but the value is zero?

Comment: BTW, if you want to determine whether anything's selected in a list or combo box, check the box's .ListIndex property.  It'll be -1 if nothing's selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsEmpty` checks whether a variable of type `Variant` contains a special value `Empty`.

What you probably meant is checking if a string is an empty string:

```
If Len(cbo_moduleName.Value) = 0 Then
    ...
End If
```